# Add the current path for the new link

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, path, window

I want add the current path for the new links (to be able to switch the language staying on the same page).

How can I add the current `window.location.pathname` to new URLs?

Comment: See history.pushState

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the js history object:

```
function changeLanguage(code){
    //possible languages
    var codes=["en","de"];
    if(!codes.find(function(a){return a==code})){
      //language not available
      console.error("unknown language");
      return;
     }
     //get current url
     url=window.location.pathname;
     for(i=0;i<codes.length;i++){
          //replace current language with new language
          url=url.replace(codes[i],code);
     }
     //"redirect" url without reloading the page
     history.pushState({},"new title",url);
     //replace content...
}
//example:
changeLanguage("de");
```

This requires the url to contain the language code:

```
http://example.com/en/main/
->
 http://example.com/de/main/
```